# Viewport different on Android landscape/portrait

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, css

i'm developing a mobile site...to test this i have created different emulator for android and use iphone emulator. The problem is that call window.innerWidth on the orientation change on iPhone the viewport change if portrait 320 and if landscape 480 but on android the viewport is the same in landscape and in portrait (for example in resolution 480x800 the viewport is 320 in landscape/portrait).
My meta for the viewport is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

it's correct the behaviour?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

The posting of your viewport meta tag is missing.
But anyway, you are right:
The innerWidth/Height do not get adapted to the orientation. If you want to handle the layout according to the orientation, i would suggest to use CSS3 media queries. 
Documentation can be found here: [CLICK](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: ok this happen only for android? because iPhone change the viewport size with different orientation and my question is if i can be confident for the behaviour of android emulator. (I've added metatag in previous post thx :) )

Comment: I'm not really sure, but i know that those kind of differences between the manufacturers stole me a lot of time. Do not try to identify the orientation yourself, it will be a mess. Use a responsive design with the help of orientation conditions inside media queries. *edit* I tested this against a couple of different phones like SGS1, Nexus, IPhone 3 and 4, so i can't tell anything about the emulator.